# When do you close? vs Until what time are you open?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, politeness, conversation

I have just came across this situation.
At I can't get rid of this question what should I say

1. when do you close
   or
2. until what time are you open?

it might sound really silly question,
but when you asking in your way,
which one would you prefer and what makes it more comfortable to say?

and it might be more silly to ask, but I am kind of wondering "when do you close" sounds a bit direct.

of course asking about the closing time is not a matter of polite or not, but it seems sounds just quick and might give the rude sense?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Asking (1.) "when" is inquiring which day (or days) of the week is the shop/business/institution closed.

Comment: Asking (2.) "what time" is to specifically find out the business working hours.

Comment: @Mari-LouA “When do you close” is fine imo and the only way that you would possibly get a date instead of a time would be if the store was closing permanently.

Comment: thank you all!!

Comment: @laurel However, there's a marked difference in answers to "When were you born?" and "What time were you born?"

Comment: "How late are you open?" would be more idiomatic in my neck of the woods.

Comment: Both are not wrong; it is just that 'until what time' is more time-specific.

Comment: If there's any difference in meaning between "When do you close?" and "Until what time are you open?", someone else will have to explain it in detail.

"Until what time are you open?" is so much more formal, it's very unlikely.

In more than 10 years working in shops, I've almost exclusively heard "What time do you close?"

How could either "seems sounds just quick and might give the rude sense"?